# is there a way (plugin) to insert html/css/images ect automatically into every wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is there a way (plugin) to insert html/css/images ect.. automatically into every wordpress post? most of my posts are going to be very similar so is there a plugin that will automatically insert the pre written  html/css/ ect in every post as opposed to me entering it manually every time.

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: You can accomplish this by editing the template for the post and adding any html/css/etc. you want.

Comment: The trivial answer to this question is "yes". Please post what you have tried and indicate specifically where you are stuck. Simply presenting a problem and asking for others to write code for you is frowned upon on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own simple function for this, see my example below:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );

function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    global $post_type;
    if( $post_type == 'post') { /* Or your custom post type, pages etc. */
        $content = 'Your custom HTML/CSS content here';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Place this in `functions.php` and it will be the default content of every new post/page/custom post type you create.

For a list of available post types, please refer to the **[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)**

Comment: I would use `$content .=` depending on the OP's needs, that way he can add original content to the stock text on a per-post basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin such as Ad injection, it will allow you to do what you need without having to alter / amend / ad any code to the templates or files